# How to specify analyzers when searching or indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a type that I need to index or search for using a different language analyzer that varies based on the language of the text in the document . How can I specify the analyzer for every search or indexing operation?

Answer (score 2):

Answered on https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/issues/271

The combination /index/type is unique in elasticsearch if you have a single type with a name property that you want to map differently you need to index to two different elasticsearch types each with its own mapping.

You can do this in NEST by explicitly specifying the typename whenever you map/index/search, no need to have two different CLR types.